# How to determine if value is a date in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I am working with arrays of values in PHP. Some of these values may include a date in various string formats.

I need to convert dates in multiple formats to their numerical equivalent (Unix timestamp). The problem is being able to determine if the string is a date.

Using

```
if (($timestamp = strtotime($str)) === false)
```

will check for a valid date from a string but how do I determine if the value should even be validated as a date?

**Example:**

```
$x = {1,2,3,"4","11/12/2009","22/12/2000",true,false};

foreach($x as $value)
{

if(is_bool($value))

if(is_string($value))

if(is_numeric($value))

if(is_date($value)) ?

...

}
```

In short, is there an easy way to check if a string value is a date?

Comment: What is this thing: `$x = { /* ... */ };`?

Comment: That is my sudo-code array :-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> In short, is there an easy way to check if a string value is a date?

Not really, seeing as it could be in an arbitrary format.

If at all possible, I would tend to leave parsing to the magic of `strtotime()`. If it manages to create a valid date, fine. If it doesn't, you'll receive `false`.

Be prepared for the possibility of false positives, though, because `strtotime()` parses even things like "Last Friday".

If `strtotime()` is too liberal for you, you could consider building a collection of date formats you want to accept, and run PHP 5.3's [`DateTime:createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) using every one of the formats on every date.

Something like (untested)

```
$formats = array("d.m.Y", "d/m/Y", "Ymd"); // and so on.....
$dates = array(1,2,3,"4","11/12/2009","22/12/2000",true,false);

foreach ($dates as $input) 
 { 
   foreach ($formats as $format)
    {
      echo "Applying format $format on date $input...<br>";

      $date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $input);
      if ($date == false) 
       echo "Failed<br>";
      else
       echo "Success<br>";
    }
 }
```

Comment: I did not think there was a quick way to do this. However, your solution works nicely. Thanks.

Comment: It appears that it is possible to do it quickly and elegantly: http://au1.php.net/checkdate#113205

Answer (score 12):

The problem with Pekka's script is that the date '2011-30-30' is also considered valid. This is the modified version.

```
$formats = array("d.m.Y", "d/m/Y", "Ymd"); // and so on.....
$dates = array(1,2,3,"4","11/12/2009","22/12/2000",true,false);

foreach ($dates as $input) 
 { 
   foreach ($formats as $format)
    {
      echo "Applying format $format on date $input...<br>";

      $date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $input);
      if ($date == false || !(date_format($date,$format) == $input) ) 
       echo "Failed<br>";
      else
       echo "Success<br>";
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Extrapolating from https://www.php.net/checkdate#113205 ;
just change the $formats array to all the formats you want to check.

```
public function convertDate($value) {

    $formats = ['M d, Y', 'Y-m-d'];
    foreach($formats as $f) {
        $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($f, $value);
        $is_date = $d && $d->format($f) === $value;

        if ( true == $is_date ) break;
    }

    return $is_date;

}
```